# IIS 7 removes Content-Disposition filename for Content-Type application/pdf

Tags: pdf, iis, content-type, content-disposition

I have the following code that returns a PDF file in my web application:

```
string path = "help.pdf";
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=help.pdf");
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Response.End();
```

When I call the handler of this code in any browser (Chrome, IE or Firefox), I get a "Save as..." dialog with the name of the page (`index.aspx`) rather than the name provided in the code (`help.pdf`).

I also checked the following:

- Tested on my local machine. It works there as expected.
- Deactivated compression in IIS: no change
- Deactivated SSL in IIS: no change
- Checked MIME types in IIS: application/pdf is configured
- Replaced Content-Type `application/pdf` with `application/octet-stream`: problem is gone (but we are using third party export tools that I can't modify in this way, so this is not a solution)

I checked the HTTP response header with all browsers. It looks like this:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:attachment
Content-Length:89407
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 07 May 2015 08:43:12 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge,chrome=1
```

As you can see the filename parameter is removed from the Content-Disposition field. So the behaviour of the browsers is correct. The web server (IIS) seems to tinker around with the header.

I found somebody with the same problem [here](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/508954-addheader-content-disposition-has-no-effect). But the problem was never solved. Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing extra space in "attachment;<remove this space> filename=help.pdf"

Comment: There's a couple of things I'd try, all stupid but they might work. First, try removing the `Content-Length` and seeing if that works. Also, try throwing a `Response.Flush()` after the `Content-Length` but before writing to the stream. There's a [thread on Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.inetserver.iis/And_FaovAU4) that suggests these things and goes into it a littler deeper.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. Modifying the code is not an option. We are using third party controls on the page that have the same problem with their "Export to PDF" feature. Besides: I already tried to modify the code in various ways (including Flush), with no effect.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: I tried what is suggested in that thread. It has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that because of an [IIS 7.5 issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979543) someone added the following lines to the `web.config` file of the application:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Force pdfs to download" preCondition="only match pdfs">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="only match pdfs">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/pdf" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```